# How do I Yield() to another thread in a Win8 C++/Xaml app?

Tags: multithreading, windows-runtime, c++-cx

**Note:** I'm using C++, not C#.

I have a bit of code that does some computation, and several bits of code that use the result. The bits that use the result are already in tasks, but the original computation is not -- it's actually in the callstack of the main thread's App::App() initialization.

Back in the olden days, I'd use:

```
while (!computationIsFinished())
    std::this_thread::yield(); // or the like, depending on API
```

Yet this doesn't seem to exist for Windows Store apps (aka WinRT, pka Metro-style). I can't use a continuation because the bits that use the results are unconnected to where the original computation takes place -- in addition to that computation not being a task anyway.

Searching found `Concurrency::Context::Yield()`, but Context appears not to exist for Windows Store apps.

So... say I'm in a task on the background thread. How do I `yield`? Especially, how do I yield in a while loop?

Comment: Could you wrap the computation in a task?

Comment: No, it's needed during initialization, on the main thread, and I don't want to block the main thread. I know there are other ways of async programming, I'm primarily wondering if yield is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, doing expensive computations in a constructor is not usually a good idea. Even less so when it's the "App" class. Also, doing heavy work in the main (ASTA) thread is pretty much forbidden in the WinRT model.

You can use `concurrency::task_completion_event<T>` to interface code that isn't task-oriented with other pieces of dependent work.

E.g. in the long serial piece of code:

```
...

task_completion_event<ComputationResult> tce;

task<ComputationResult> computationTask(tce); 

// This task is now tied to the completion event. 
// Pass it along to interested parties.

try
{
    auto result = DoExpensiveComputations();

    // Successfully complete the task.
    tce.set(result);
}
catch(...)
{
    // On failure, propagate the exception to continuations.
    tce.set_exception(std::current_exception());
}

...
```

Should work well, but again, I recommend breaking out the computation into a task of its own, and would probably start by not doing it during construction... surely an anti-pattern for a responsive UI. :)

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that this is "expensive" computation, but it isn't. For my problem, it looks like a completion event will work. However, I'm still wondering: is there any way to yield()?

Answer (score 0):

Qt simply uses Sleep(0) in their WinRT yield implementation.